# Why Jprofiler 9.11 stops doing profiling (CPU views - Hotspots) after some time?

Tags: profiling, jprofiler

Jprofiler version 9.11 stops doing profiling after ~20 Minutes. Is there any hidden configuration that allows profiling for a longer period of time? Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: I just add some more memory for use in those files: ~/.jprofiler9/jprofiler.vmoptions or ~/Library/Preferences/jprofiler.vmoptions

Comment: What do you mean exactly  by "stop profiling"? Does the UI stop responding? Is there are file %TEMP%\jprofiler_error.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI is not responding! I increase the memory size and do change in configuration so that the graphs and the statistics are updated in a lower frequency. Updates are triggered after each 30s vs. default 5s!